# Spring boot, zuul, oauth2 authentication problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-zuul

I have been trying to build an application with Zuul, Eureka and Spring boot and recently I decided to attempt the login. As a reminder, I have already configured the authentication service (using OAuth 2.0) and I can successfully authenticate using CURL. I can also make get petitions to other microservices that have protected resources (again only with CURL because I can inject the token in the authentication header). My concern is that I want to do this with Zuul as a gateway.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Zuul runs on port 8080** and
**Auth Service runs on port 1992**
when I call authentication service directly on **http://localhost:19992/oauth/token** endpoint, it is generating token as following.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
**But, When I try to access authentication service through zuul server it is showing unAuthorized**
**http://localhost:8080/auth-service/oauth/token**
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

**My Zuul Server application.yml configuration**

````
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
  instance:
    hostname: zuul-service
    instance-id: ${eureka.instance.hostname}:${random.int}
    prefer-ip-address: true
zuul:
  sensitive-headers: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization```

My Question is
1. why token is not generated through zuul server?
2. How token propagate through multiple microservices?

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance. 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQUvE.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spsqf.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp84x.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been adding Authorization in sensativeHeaders.
This won't allow Authorization header to propagate downstream services. I removed Authorization from sensitive header then it worked like charm.